Does the getResourceAsStream method of the Class class in Java read the file given as an argument every time it is called?
I am developing a Java project which contains a properties file from which properties need to be extracted frequently. I have a function:
        @Override
    public String getPropertyValue(String property) {
        Properties properties=new Properties();
        
        try{
        properties.load(Configuration.class.getResourceAsStream("MyProperties.properties"));
        
              
        }catch(IOException e){
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE,e.getMessage(),e);
            //e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        } 
        String prop = properties.getProperty(property);
        if (prop== null)
        {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"Property "+property+" not found");
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        return prop;
    }

I expect the getPropertyValue function to be called frequently in the code. I tried searching through the documents as well the decompiled source code of the getResourceAsStream method but I couldn't find any information about whether it actually opens and reads the file whose name is given as the argument everytime it is called.
I was thinking if this is the case, then I can potentially eliminate expensive file i/o operations by implementing some kind of in-memory caching. I can store the key-value pairs which are present in the file all at once or every time a new key is read and avoid reading the file if I find that the particular key has already been cached.
So, how exactly does the method call work if I give it the name of a properties file as an input?
TL;DR: Does calling getResourceAsStream("<name of a file.properties>") perform a file read operation internally every time it is called?
I tried looking up the documentation to the method online and seeing if a similar question has been asked already. I also tried to understand the decompiled source code of the method, however, I was not able to understand it since it contained too many advanced Java constructs which I am not aware of. Since this is part of a large project which contains several other file i/o operations, it is not possible for me to track individual file i/o syscalls.

Yes it does read the resource every time. The JVM has no way of knowing whether that resource will ever be read again or how big it is and therefore cannot reliably implement a caching mechanism.

It's not a "file" as such, but a resource. It might be a file on disk, it might be an entry in a jar (more normally). If the Properties are of a modest size then why not leave them in memory? btw, afaicr, ::load does not close the stream

getResourceAsStream isn't reading anything. It's just getting a handle on the resource. properties.load is the one actually reading the stream.

So is properties.load reading the file each time? Basically, is a file being read each time the getPropertyValue function is called?

Yes, though as I have already said, it is not possible to know whether it's an actual file

Most properties files are probably small enough to hold in memory. If so, hold the Properties in an instance variable and load it 'lazily', e.g.: @Override public String getPropertyValue(String property) {if (properties == null) {try (InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(PROPERTIES_RESOURCE_URL)) {properties.load(in);} catch (IOException e) {logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Problem loading properties from url " + PROPERTIES_RESOURCE_URL, e);System.exit(1);}}

String prop = properties.getProperty(property);if (prop == null) {logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Property " + property + " not found");throw new NullPointerException();}return prop;} (Splice that to the end of the last)

fyi, since 1.7 you can do:  String prop = properties.getProperty(property);Objects.requireNonNull(prop, "Property " + property + " not found"); So I'd splice that instead ;)
